# Comparing equality of strings, but also only comparing String objects (hard type check)

Tags: java

In the middle of a refactoring, I've noticed that anything (because it's inherited from Object) can be compared using the `equals()` method, but I want to call a method that only compares Strings, because that would let the compiler stop me if I'm comparing objects of different types.

There's any built-in method in Java that do this?

Comment: So you're saying that you use equals in object that are String or not? Show us the piece of code...

Comment: int compareTo(String anotherString)? When both Strings are equal it will return 0

Comment: compareTo is close! Unfortunately, as it's intended for purposes other than equality comparison, I also have to check if it's equal to zero, not so convenient.

Comment: @Julio Rodrigues what if yo check using instanceof that the object is a String? and then call the equals only in that case.

Comment: @Alboz, that would work, but I think that it's too much code for this task.

Comment: You could also compare the hashcodes oft both strings with == ;)

Comment: @Julio Rodrigues it's an additional if condition. The other solutions requires to write your own method or refactor the existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Julio Rodrigues you can use the method contentEquals()

```
string1.contentEquals(string2)
```

It's case sensitive, and it's **only** present in the class String (not inherited from object),.

Comment: This is nearly right, but `String.contentEquals()` takes a `CharSequence` rather than a `String`, so you can pass it a `String` or a `StringBuffer` or a `CharBuffer` and it won't complain.

Comment: @chiastic-security yes you can pass to it every class that implements the Interface CharSequence, but I thought perhaps it can still can suit him... Anyway let's see.

Answer (score 1):

If you need something that returns a `boolean`, you can write your own static method that takes two `String` instances and uses `.compareTo()` or `.equals()` behind the scenes. If the signature requires `String`s, the compiler will enforce it.

```
public static boolean compareStrings(String a, String b) {
    return a.equals(b);
}
```

This will throw a `NullPointerException` if `a` is `null`, which may or may not be what you want. It would be easy enough to put in a check.

Comment: I can't find this method, it's the compareTo? Unfortunately, as it's intended for purposes other than equality comparison, I also have to check if it's equal to zero, not so convenient.

Comment: @chiastic-security that method doesn't exist on String.java

Comment: Sorry, you're right. It's in `Integer`, not `String`. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: @JulioRodrigues Corrected, with a suggestion for how to get round the equal-to-zero check.

Answer (score 0):

Use **FindBugs**, static code analysis, quite easy; with IDE plugins, with separate GUI app. That will mark such problematic uses and others.

That is a better shot-gun approach: repeatable and finding several issues. Absolute fun.